# htaccess mod_expires not reflecting

Tags: .htaccess

I had following lines in httaccess...

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
</filesmatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

There was 0 issue regarding leverage browser cache.

Then i added below lines...

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Now all of sudden i am getting leverage browser caching issue for most of the css files and google fonts.

http response for wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/static/css/layerslider.css) is as below...

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK =>
Last-Modified => Fri, 13 Nov 2015 02:21:04 GMT
ETag => "3d5c-52462b61daaf0-gzip"
Cache-Control => max-age=86400
Expires => Thu, 13 Apr 2017 06:34:08 GMT
Content-Type => text/css
X-Port => port_10078
X-Cacheable => YES
Date => Wed, 12 Apr 2017 16:41:15 GMT
Age => 36427
Connection => close
X-Cache => cached
X-Cache-Hit => HIT
X-Backend => all_requests
Accept-Ranges => bytes
```

access time for css is one month. then why is google (as well as pingdom) showing 24 hours expire time?

see image below...

[image]

Comment: why is down vote?

Comment: `Header append Vary Accept-Encoding` ie without `:`

Comment: @Deadooshka The trailing colon on the header name is _optional_.

Comment: Please include the HTTP response headers for these requests. Btw, you shouldn't be using both mod_headers and mod_expires to set the Cache-Control max-age header (this is what mod_expires does). `Header set Cache-Control ...` will be overriding your mod_expires directives, so the mod_expires directives aren't really doing much anyway. (I didn't downvote btw.)

Comment: @w3dk question updated, please check.

Comment: you get `Cache-Control: max-age=86400` (sec.) that probably means your htaccess is not affected

Comment: @Deadooshka But if the mod_expires and/or mod_headers directives had executed then you would expect to see `Cache-Control: max-age=2592000` (or `2678400`) - so something has been affected?

Comment: The `Vary` header should not affect this. But where is the `Vary` header in the response - it's not present in the headers shown? Do you have an intermediary cache (`X-Cache`, `X-Cache-Hit`?)? CDN? Proxy server?